# iReport does not go to the preview mood with graphs

Tags: plugins, netbeans, ireport, netbeans-plugins

I used to generate a ireport to [this](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4425/ireport) plugin which working with netbeans. my ireports are correctly working without graphs. when I add a graph to my report template and try to go to the preview mood it auto switch to the designer mood. it does not preview. I have no idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. my ireport template does not align properly when I add a graphs to the report. that is why it happen